# \footcite and \footcitetext produce empty citation in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, citing

I'm using `biblatex` with `bibtex` in the beamer document class. In a very weird way the `\footcite` produces a rather empty citation "2." In the example, whereas `\footcitefull` gives a very nice citation.

My problem now is that I would like to place a citation within a column and/or block environment, where according to other posts I would have to use `\footnotemark` and `\footcitetext`, which would simply write "3." in the footer.

For image, see:

[image]

My question would be:

1. Is there an error in my TeX or
2. is there an equivalent to `\footcitefull` in `\footcitetext`?

   ```
   documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   %\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   %\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
   %\usepackage{colortbl}
   %\usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage[lf]{venturis}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   %\usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
   %\usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{pgf}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage[citetracker=true,sorting=none,backend=bibtex,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
   \bibliography{../literature.bib} 
   \frame{
   \frametitle{Introduction -- Electron Magnetic Chiral Dichroism}

   \begin{itemize}
       \item Discovered due to analogies between polarization and scattering vector in theoretical treatment.\footfullcite{emcd_nature}
       \item Recent research focused on: signal enhancement, electron ``vortex'' beams.\footcite{emcd_theory}
   \end{itemize}

   \begin{block}{Intrinsic Setup}
       \begin{columns}[m]
           \column{.4\textwidth}
           \begin{figure}[h]
               \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{images/apertures_0.pdf}
               \caption{Schematic}
           \end{figure}

           \column{.4\textwidth}
           \begin{itemize}
               \item The ``usual'' setup.
               \item Phase shift of $\pi/2$ of one Bragg beam due to dynamical diffraction effects.
               \item Dependent on sample thickness, orientation and crystal quality.
               \item Other setup to overcome dynamical diffraction effects?
               \item \textbf{Candidates:}
               \begin{itemize}
                   \item Electron vortex beams (fork aperture, stigmator).
                   \item Twin aperture with electrostatic phase plates.
               \end{itemize}
           \end{itemize}
       \end{columns}
   \end{block}
   ```

   }

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The "rather empty" footnote citations correspond to the citation label. Since you use the default `numeric` style, the label is simply the `labelnumber`. Why not try using a style with more verbose labels, like `authortitle` or `verbose`?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the style `phys` as I want to have more nicely formated citations.
But I have to admit, it is working with style `authortitle`.
Any idea why it's not working with `phys`?

Comment: Because biblatex-phys is also a numeric style.